# Cookie with attribute SameSite Lax is included in the headers of a cross origin post request

Tags: javascript, session, cookies, fetch, csrf

As i've understood if I set the attribute `sameSite` of a `cookie` to `Lax` it won't be included in the headers of a post request when it is being sent from a different origin.

So I have a next app running in `http://localhost:4000`
and another malicious app running in `http://localhost:8080`.

I open both in the same browser (chrome) and I log in in `http://localhost:4000`. After i do so a sess cookie is being created which has SameSite Lax as checked in chrome dev tools application tab.

Now the endpoint `http://localhost:4000/createFood` accepts post requests and creates a new food if sess cookie is present(and matches a session).

So to simulate a CSRF attack I go to the malicious `http://localhost:8080` where I have put the following request

```
fetch("http://localhost:4000/createFood ", {
      credentials: "include",
      method: "POST",
      mode: "no-cors",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({name: "Banana", taste: "very good"}),
    });
```

I would expect when i check the req.headers.cookies in my api that the sess cookie won't be present because it has sameSite = Lax but it is there although the post request is being sent from a different origin (from http://localhost:8080 to http://localhost:4000)!

Why is the sess cookie there?

Comment: No because SameSite attribute is set to Lax specifically. It probably has to do with localhost...

Comment: Indeed, `localhost:4000` and `localhost:8080` count as the same site. The port does not matter.